# Is it possible to add manual page breaks to PivotTables (Excel Interop)?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, excel-interop, page-break

When programmatically generating a "normal" Excel sheet, a Range's PageBreak property can be set to xlPageBreakManual and then you can specify where the page is to break with code like so:

```
workbook.Worksheets[0].VPageBreaks.Add(sheet.Range["G1"]);
```

...but is this possible when printing a PivotTable? I would think not, since the PivotTable is fed from a datasource (a page of "raw data" in my case, which I subsequently hide), but if it is, I would like to know how.

This is what I do now to prepare the PivotTablized sheet for printing:

```
private void FormatPivotTable()
{
    . . .
    ConfigureForPrinting(_xlPivotTableSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count);
}

private void ConfigureForPrinting(int finalRow)
{
    string lastColumn = GetExcelTextColumnName(_xlPivotTableSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count);
    string printArea = String.Format("A1:{0}{1}", lastColumn, finalRow);
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = printArea;
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 50;

    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.BottomMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.HeaderMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.FooterMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);

    string rangeToRepeat = string.Format("$A$6:${0}$7", lastColumn);
    _xlPivotTableSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = rangeToRepeat;
}
```

What the user wants is that each logical block of data be kept together on a sheet, so that a block (5 rows) does not span more than one sheet. IOW, if there are less than 5 rows of space on the current page when a block begins, skip to the next page with a page break.

Is this possible with PivotTables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the that when you are referring to *"logical blocks of data"* it means data corresponding to a `PivotFieldItem`. If that is the case the try this:

Set these `PivotTable` properties to `TRUE`:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PrintTitles = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
```

Also set to `TRUE` the `LayoutPageBreak` property of the `PivotField` for which you want to set a page break every time there is a change of item:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Class").LayoutPageBreak = True
```

*Also need to set this property to `TRUE` in case there are items with only one record.*

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Class").LayoutBlankLine = True
```

*Replace "PivotTable1" and "Class" values as required*

*Although the commands above are in `VBA` they should give you a good idea of how to set these properties using `C#`*